# LINQ: Add to list for each item

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to convert the following line to LINQ, what is the recommended way to do so? I have the following code:

```
IEnumerable<person> result = Enumerable.Empty<person>();
var list1 = getlist1(..)
var repository = new Repository();
for(int i = 0; i < list1.Length; i++)
{
    result = result.Union(repository.GetList(list1[i].ID));
}
```

I want to call repository.GetList for each item in list1, and add the results to a list.

Comment: what is `list1`? You have it as a `var` and as the result of some mythical method...what is it's type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<person> result = list1.SelectMany(i => repository.GetList(i.ID));
```

And if you want them as a list:

```
 IList<person> result = list1.SelectMany(i => repository.GetList(i.ID)).ToList();
```

Comment: I think you need `SelectMany` so that it is a flattened list

Comment: Thanks a lot, SelectMany to the rescue!